# Alternative for large switch statment

Tags: javascript, html

I have bit of a problem. I have app with large amount of buttons that i wanna trigger on keyboard press. Currently i'm using switch statemnt for it, but as I want to get more and more buttons (about 25) switch statment gets larger and larger. How can I replace my switch statment and keep my functionality?

The code:

```html
<button id="left_button" action-name="left" class="button"></button>
<button id="enter_button" action-name="enter" class="button"></button>
<button id="right_button" action-name="right" class="button"></button>
<button id="return_button" action-name="return" class="button"></button>
<button id="down_button" action-name="down" class="button"></button>
```

```js
function animateButton(div_id) {
    
    div_id.classList.add("boxshadow");

    var data_action = div_id.getAttribute("action-name")
    
    //this sends data further down the pipeline
    RequestPress(data_action)

    setTimeout(function() {
        div_id.classList.remove("boxshadow");
    }, 400);

    
}

var up_button = document.getElementById('up_button')
var right_button = document.getElementById('right_button')
var left_button = document.getElementById('left_button')
var down_button = document.getElementById('down_button')
var enter_button = document.getElementById('enter_button')
var esc_button = document.getElementById('return_button')

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                animateButton(up_button)
                break;
            case 39:
                animateButton(right_button)
                break;
            case 40:
                animateButton(down_button)
                break;
            case 37:
                animateButton(left_button)
                break;
            case 13:
                animateButton(enter_button)
                break;
            case 27:
                animateButton(esc_button)
                break;
        }
});
```

note: I don't want to use jQuery

Comment: even a long switch statement is fine and highly performant. An alternative would be a `for` loop and the usage of an array or object. However, it will be comparably slow. Code should be performant and readable instead of being minimalistic short

Comment: Worth pointing out: `keyCode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), the modern equivalent is just [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code). And I'd suggest perhaps storing the matching code in a data attribute, rather than as the elements ID.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74530839/alternative-for-large-switch-statment#comment131564935_74530839) [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is also a typical alternative. The difference being that [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) represents the character value while [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) represents the physical key.

Comment: You can use this event viewer to see keyboard events and get the values you need for your application: https://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer.html

Comment: Can use `Object` with code as key and button id as value, e.g. `var obj = { 13: 'enter_button', 38: 'up_button', ...so on }` and then on event listener method, you can `var buttonId = obj[e.code]; buttonId && animateButton(document.getElementById(buttonId))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through children of the wrapper div of these buttons and make a look up dictionary where key is `name` of the button and value is the `id`:

```
const el = document.getElementById("buttons").children;
const dict = Array.from(el).reduce((a, {id, name}) => ({...a, [name]: id}),{});
```

and inside the `EventListener` just look for the key already in the dictionary as:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (dict[e.keyCode]) {
    animateButton(document.getElementById(dict[e.keyCode]));
  }
});
```

Here is an example:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("buttons").children;
const dict = Array.from(el).reduce((a, {id, name}) => ({...a, [name]: id}),{});
console.log(dict);
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="left_button" name=37 class="button"></button>
  <button id="right_button" name=39 class="button"></button>
  <button id="down_button" name=40 class="button"></button>
</div>
```

**Note:** as you said you only have 25 buttons, so it's not a big deal for a modern machine to loop through 25 items.

Hope it helps!